# Do Qt based applications run better on KDE Plasma than on Gnome with Qt installed as a dependency?

Tags: linux, qt, gnome, kde-plasma

As KDE Plasma Linux Desktop Environment is built on Qt and therefore Qt baked into the system. Are there any extra overheads and extra complexities by running a Qt application on Gnome with Qt installed separately. Apologies if this question has been asked previously.

Many thanks.

I have been running my Qt application on Gnome for a good few years with no major problems, so my question is purely an academic one for the moment.

Comment: The only possible overhead you could be relatively sure about is the time required to load Qt libraries and the memory required by them. If they are shared libraries, and any other program using Qt with the same shared libraries is already running, there would be no substantial difference; fundamentally, it's similar to opening a new tab in the browser. In a Qt based desktop those libraries are already loaded, but if the app uses static linking (so, it has *its own* Qt lib) you lose that benefit anyway. There are other aspects to consider, obviously, but they are not arbitrarily quantifiable.